# Preg replace soundcloud link from text

Tags: php, replace, soundcloud

```
$text='some text and text http://soundcloud.com/disclosuremusic/whats-in-your-head some other text http://soundcloud.com/bad-panda-records/indian-wells-04 and again text blabla'; 

$text = preg_replace('#(?:https?://).soundcloud\.com/([\-a-z0-9_]+/[\-a-z0-9_]+)#siU','<object height="81" width="100%"><param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=$1&amp;g=bb"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=$1&amp;g=bb" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed></object> <a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Trying to pregreplace a sound cloud links from text but seems to be with no luck. Thanks

Comment: use some function like [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#92456) to first escape all the special characters from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "." before "soundcloud\.com" is failing the match

```
'%(?:https?://)(?:www\.)?soundcloud\.com/([\-a-z0-9_]+/[\-a-z0-9_]+)%im'
```

Do you need to account for www. at all?

Comment: thanks a lot mate you saved my hours :) its showed me a user/song text so after i just added ?url=http://soundcloud.com/$1 to link and its what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
$text = preg_replace('/((http?:\/\/)soundcloud\.com\/([\-a-z0-9_]+/[\-a-z0-9_]+))/i','<object height="81" width="100%"><param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=$1&amp;g=bb"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=$1&amp;g=bb" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"></embed></object> <a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

You had an extra dot before "soundcloud" and you were not properly escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$text='some text and text http://soundcloud.com/qcntoz some other text http://soundcloud.com/qcntoz and again text blabla'; 

$text = preg_replace('#(?:https?://).soundcloud\.com/([\-a-z0-9_]+/[\-a-z0-9_]+)#siU','<object height="81" width="100%"><param name="movie" value="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=$1&amp;g=bb"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed allowscriptaccess="always" height="81" src="http://player.soundcloud.com/player.swf?url=$1&amp;g=bb" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%"> </embed></object> <a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
```

Comment: Please format this and provide an explanation, it is not readable, thanks!